# Replacing vi by vim

Tags: command-line, configuration, vim

How do I replace `vi` by `vim` so that when I type `vi` in terminal `vim` is opened?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add

```
alias vi=vim
```

to `~/.bashrc` . This will start `vim` whenever you type `vi`.

Note that in Ubuntu 10.10 (and I think also 10.04) `vi` is already mapped to `vim`.

Comment: Sorry for another silly question, but where is `.bashrc` located ? I am quite new to Ubuntu.

Comment: In your home directory. Just type `vim ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Actually, 'vi' has pointed to some variation of 'vim' since almost forever in Ubuntu (see my answer about alternatives to know how to change which variation).

Answer (score 26):

'vi' in Ubuntu already starts 'vim', although by default it starts 'vim-tiny' (which comes closest to the original 'vi' in its (lack of) features).  You can see this with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --display vi
```

If you want it to use another version of vim, then make sure it's installed and run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config vi
```

Comment: Can I use update-alternatives for other applications, what does update-alternatives do, does it installs extra features ?

Comment: Yes you can. It updates alternatives. No, it doesn't.
If you want to know more use `man update-alternatives` or start a new question.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, instead of the workaround that was accepted!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Peter Smit has suggested.  You can do the following as well to make that change system wide rather than just your account.

add `alias vi='vim'` to /etc/bash.bashrc

or create a symlink to vim

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vi`

However on my system both /usr/bin/vim and /usr/bin/vi are symlinks to /etc/alternatives/vim

Comment: The symlink is a bad suggestion: use update-alternatives to manage this in Ubuntu.

Comment: yes I agree do it the correct way.  I didn't know that vim was using the alternatives system.